# Overlapping Divs while zooming (html,css animation)

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to zoom in on a `div` but it keeps overlapping with the adjacent `div`.

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
    
.zoom {
 /* padding: 50px; */
 background-color: green;
 transition: transform .2s;
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.zoom:hover {
 -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari 3-8 */
 transform: scale(1.5); 
}
    
     
.nopadding {
 padding: 0 !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding box1">
      <div class="zoom" id="img1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding box1">
      <div class="zoom" id="img2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding box1">
      <div class="zoom" id="img3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding box1">
      <div class="zoom" id="img4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is on hover the `div` should pop up and not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

To your css, add:

```
.box1{
overflow: hidden;
height: 200px;
}
```

and also edit `.zoom`:

```
.zoom{
    background-color: green;
    transition: transform .2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: no it's not working , i want to achieve this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_zoom_hover  effect but with 4 divs

Comment: It is advisable you give `box1` a defined height (in your case 200px) then add `z-index:10; position:absolute` to `.zoom:hover`  so as not to affect the position of all other  `box1`